# Numerical differentation - finding maxima

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, maxima-minima

I was analyzing my data and made a graph of it ($ f(x)$)  and I wanted to find the maxima of $ \frac {df(x)}{dx}  $.

The derivative of a function is defined as $\;$ $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

Well, I did the numerical differentation of my data in Origin which is more precise (I did it manually too). Then I found the maximal value of that. I picked the maxima from my numerical differentition list automically even though the data here had negative sign but I suppose I should take the absolute value of the numbers in that list if I am finding the point of my curve where the $f(x)$ change is the most rapid, right?

I know it is a trivial question but I somehow froze here.

An example: $f(x) = \{f(x_0),f(x_1),f(x_2),f(x_3),f(x_4)\}$ and $x = \{x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$, then

$ \frac {df(x)}{dx} = \{ \frac {f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0},\frac {f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1},\frac {f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2},\frac {f(x_4)-f(x_3)}{x_4-x_3} \}$  corresponds to $\{-4, 1,0, 3\}$

so the maxima of $ \frac {df(x)}{dx} $ is $4$ right?

Comment: Your ansatz is correct. However, you work with discrete data. Therefore, you must be sure that the data is smooth enough. Otherwise you may find wrong solutions.

Comment: Yeah my data is really nice. But thanks, i was kind of insecure. I have to calculate it correctly.

Comment: If $x=[0,1,2,3]$ and $f(x) = [0,0,1,0]$ then your algorithm will not work. Why not just find the largest element in $f(x)$ as the one greater than or equal to any other. Why do you think numerical differentiation is a good method here?

Comment: This approach is right. You might want to consider using a different approximation rule for the derivatives at the interior data points though. Instead of forward-differences, the midpoint derivative approximation ($f'(x)\approx (f(x+h)-f(x-h))/2h$) actually has a better error bound than the forward-difference rule (assuming the data is smooth).